# Как запустить exe файл через php с разрешением пользователя?

Tags: php

На его компьютере.

Comment: только один законный способ - дать пользователю ссылку, что бы он сказал, а потом сам запустил.

незаконный способ: использовать уязвимости в браузере.

третий способ: использовать, что браузер сам запустит другую программу для обработки определенного типа файла - например, торрент клиент или microsoft word. Но клиент может у себя настроить достаточно нетривиальным способом (например, открывать pdf файлы winrar'ом).

Comment: Понятно же, что вообще говоря такой возможности быть не должно, а то каждая веб-страница захочет выполнить `format c:` на машине пользователя.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[exec()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php)

Я еще вот такой вариант в прошлом юзал:

```
function _exec($cmd) {
   $WshShell = new COM("WScript.Shell");
   $oExec = $WshShell->Run($cmd, 0,false);
   echo $cmd;
   return $oExec == 0 ? true : false;
}
_exec("youexe.exe");
```

Comment: этот файл запускаеться у клиента да

Comment: @cas-live у клиента никак не запустить по соображениям безопасности. Хотя если на клиенте стоит какой-то сервер-приёмник, то вполне возможно.

Comment: Да установлена программа

Comment: Например как работает программа торрент а именно магнет ссылка

Comment: @cas-live по этому поводу ничего не знаю.

Comment: Скажите а будет работать вот это код <?php 
exec('c:\file.exe'); 
?>

Comment: Локально работает

Answer (score 0):

Если на стороне сервера, то:

[дока](http://dead-krolik.info/2007/06/19/zapusk-vneshnego-prilozheniya-v-php-exec-system-popen-passthru-proc_open)